# XML query very slow, when .value method on XML type contains attribute filter

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql, xquery

I have a single XML value. It contains quite a lot of XML, about 13 MB.
The file is available publicly at https://www.profinfo.pl/export/bookseller.xml
In fact it contains an invalid character, but I remove all such characters before passing it to SQL Server.

The file contains the following XML structure:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<products>
    <product>
        <productId><![CDATA[108316]]></productId>
        <productCode><![CDATA[PIP-6500:201903]]></productCode>
        <productDateAdd><![CDATA[2019-03-15 14:54:52]]></productDateAdd>
        <productDateUpdate><![CDATA[2019-03-15 15:07:20]]></productDateUpdate>
        <productPrice><![CDATA[67.00]]></productPrice>
        <productNettoPrice><![CDATA[62.04]]></productNettoPrice>
        <productName><![CDATA[Państwo i Prawo - Nr 3/2019 [877]]]></productName>
        <productState><![CDATA[]]></productState>
        <productRateTax><![CDATA[8]]></productRateTax>
        <productBarcode><![CDATA[]]></productBarcode>
        <productUrl><![CDATA[https://www.profinfo.pl/sklep/panstwo-i-prawo-nr-32019-877,7255,r,2019,nr,3.html]]></productUrl>
        <productImages>
            <productImage><![CDATA[https://static.profinfo.pl/image/core_products/2019/3/15/a6e51ae4589402ae9e895c97eb42671e/admin/shop/0031-0980_877.jpg]]></productImage>
            <productImage><![CDATA[https://static.profinfo.pl/image/core_products/2019/3/15/2b0c1bdae2ca13e745d2860428317e74/admin/shop/0031-0980_877.jpg]]></productImage>
            <productImage><![CDATA[https://static.profinfo.pl/image/core_products/2019/3/15/ae609e0b6df358538f385fe4c668ab61/admin/shop/0031-0980_877.jpg]]></productImage>
        </productImages>
        <productCategories>
            <productCategory ID="144"><![CDATA[Historia, teoria i filozofia prawa]]></productCategory>
        </productCategories>
        <productAuthors>
            <productAuthor><![CDATA[Andrzej Wr&oacute;bel]]></productAuthor>
        </productAuthors>
        <productAttributes>
            <productAttribute name="Format"><![CDATA[]]></productAttribute>
            <productAttribute name="Wydanie"><![CDATA[]]></productAttribute>
            <productAttribute name="Medium"><![CDATA[Czasopismo papier]]></productAttribute>
            <productAttribute name="Rodzaj"><![CDATA[]]></productAttribute>
            <productAttribute name="Rok publikacji"><![CDATA[2019]]></productAttribute>
            <productAttribute name="Spis treści"><![CDATA[&lt;p&gt;&lt;strong&gt;TREŚĆ ZESZYTU 3/2019 &bdquo;PAŃSTWA I PRAWA&rdquo;&lt;/strong&gt;&lt;/p&gt;]]></productAttribute>
            <productAttribute name="Wydawnictwo"><![CDATA[Wolters Kluwer Polska]]></productAttribute>
            <productAttribute name="Okładka"><![CDATA[]]></productAttribute>
            <productAttribute name="Liczba stron"><![CDATA[]]></productAttribute>
            <productAttribute name="Opis katalogowy 500"><![CDATA[]]></productAttribute>
            <productAttribute name="Opis"><![CDATA[]]></productAttribute>
            <productAttribute name="Stan prawny"><![CDATA[]]></productAttribute>
            <productAttribute name="ISBN"><![CDATA[]]></productAttribute>
            <productAttribute name="Wersja publikacji"><![CDATA[Czasopismo papier]]></productAttribute>
            <productAttribute name="KodTowaru"><![CDATA[PIP-6500:201903]]></productAttribute>
            <productAttribute name="Dostępność"><![CDATA[]]></productAttribute>
            <productAttribute name="DrukNaŻyczenie"><![CDATA[0]]></productAttribute>
        </productAttributes>
    </product>
    …
</products>
```

Now, a want to execute following query in SQL:

```sql
SELECT
    product.value('productId[1]', 'VARCHAR(50)') AS id,
    product.value('(productAttributes/productAttribute[@name="Format"])[1]', 'NVARCHAR(255)') AS format
FROM @xml.nodes('/products/product') p(product)
```

The problem is, that the query is extremely slow.
I found the way to overcome this limitation. I can rewrite this query extracting `productAttributes` node as a separate XML and query only this part:

```sql
SELECT
    product.value('productId[1]', 'VARCHAR(50)') AS id,
    attrib.value('productAttribute[@name="Format"][1]', 'NVARCHAR(255)') AS format
FROM @xml.nodes('/products/product') p(product)
    OUTER APPLY (SELECT product.query('productAttributes/productAttribute') AS attrib) a
```

but still I don't understand why the first query has such low performance.

For testing I limited the size of the returned data to the TOP 100 rows and I tried to compare the plans of both queries.

The most suspicious fragment is the XML Reader with the XPath filter, which returns 3139900 rows.

[image: Query plan]

This is equal to 1847 (number of `product` elements in whole file) times 17 (number of `productAttribute` elements in each product) times 100 (number of top returned rows).
Without limiting this function will return 1847 * 1847 * 17 = 57993953, which I think explains the low performance. It grows quadratically with the number of products in te XML file.

Interestingly, the complexity of the first, much slower query is estimated at 31% of the batch, second at 69%.

Does anyone know why filtering without an additional `.query` method is so expensive?

Comment: Try `product.value('(productId[1]/text())[1]'....` and `product.value('(productAttributes[1]/productAttribute[@name="Format"]/text())[1]'....`

Comment: Adding call of `text()` function doesn't change performance. Query still create plan of quadratic complexity.

Answer (score 2):

Please try the following approach.

It takes **less than one second** to process your 13 MB XML file on my machine. I also needed to remove a some kind of special character to make the XML file well-formed.

Points to mention:

- We are loading entire XML file into a SQL Server table with one single row. All this instead of loading XML file into a variable of XML type in a memory.
- `OUTER APPLY` simulates `LEFT OUTER JOIN`. We need this because XML has two main hierarchies (one-to-many) product-to-productAttributes.
- Behind the scenes, while dealing with XML, SQL Server creates
  temporary tables. That's why query execution plan shows Table Value Function with XML reader for each.
- It is a best practice to use `text()` at the end of each XPath
  expressions for XML elements for the XQuery `.value()` method. It is SQL Server XQuery peculiarity. And I don't see that you are doing that.

**SQL**

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE(
    ID INT IDENTITY(1, 1) PRIMARY KEY,
    XmlColumn XML
);

INSERT INTO @tbl(XmlColumn)
SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET(BULK N'c:\Temp\bookseller.xml', SINGLE_BLOB) AS x;

SELECT c.value('(productId/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(10)') AS productId
    , x.value('text()[1]', 'VARCHAR(255)') AS [Format]
FROM @tbl CROSS APPLY XmlColumn.nodes('/products/product') AS t1(c)
    OUTER APPLY t1.c.nodes('productAttributes/productAttribute[@name="Format"]') AS t2(x);
```

**Partial Output**

```
+-----------+--------+
| productId | Format |
+-----------+--------+
|    108008 | NULL   |
|    108017 | NULL   |
|    108316 | NULL   |
|    108325 | NULL   |
|    108574 | NULL   |
|    108589 | A5     |
|    108595 | B5     |
+-----------+--------+
```

Comment: I know the XML isn't well formed. I wrote this at the beginning of the question.  
I also  know how to process this XML fast. Second query in question takes less than second to process all data.  
What I want to know is why simple query by `product.value('(productAttributes/productAttribute[@name="Format"])[1]', 'NVARCHAR(255)')` create plan of quadratic complexity.

Comment: @keiichi, I updated the answer with more explanations in the bulleted list.

Comment: Just adding text() actually improved performance a lot in my case. A peculiarity indeed.